# HTML Form Verification not working in IE11

Tags: html

For college we need to create a website. I'm trying to get a working form with verification as a placeholder for a login form.
Due to limitations on the college computers I can't save/use JavaScript.

My problem is that the form won't work properly on IE11. It's just skipping the verification and redirecting to 'Index.html'. 
Is there a way to get this working?

```
<form action="Index.html">
<label for="choose">Username</label>
<input id="choose" name="Username" pattern="[S/s]uper[U/u]ser">
<label for="choose">Password</label>
<input id="choose" name="Password" pattern="ROOT">
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Ps. I know the code is insecure and can be bypassed very easily but as I said it's just to act as a working placeholder

Answer (score 1):

(Might be too late for your answer but just found this searching for something else)

Even though you have patterns on the fields, the patterns are ignored for blank fields. You need the "required" attribute to make the validation check to see that something has been entered. I also fixed your pattern for the username.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Index.html">
        <label for="username">Username</label> 
        <input required id="username"
            name="Username" 
            pattern="([Ss]uper[Uu]ser)"/> 
        <br/>
        <label for="password">Password</label> 
        <input required id="password"
            name="Password" pattern="ROOT"/>
        <br/>    
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```